# Regex for matching digits followed by . (dot) then digits followed by . and so on

Tags: .net, regex, digits

Currently I have this regex: `[\d\.]+` I'm testing it with Regex Hero. You can check it working [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=095210cf-d2b2-43ca-a968-c65351d86941).

It correctly reports 5 matches for these values:

```
1.1.4.3.
11.1.2.4.4.4.5
2
4.4
2.1.1
```

The problem is that it also matches the final . in the first value `1.1.4.3.`

How can I exclude this last . and only match the value `1.1.4.3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

Should work, assuming two consecutive `.`s aren't allowed. Otherwise, just change the `\.` to `\.+`.

Comment: I voted for you in the moderator election... and I'll vote again in the next one. :) You're a great guy... can I say a super smart one. Keep helping and you'll learn more and more because is giving that we receive. There's no limit for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want:

```
@"^(\d+\.)*\d+$"
```

Comment: Thanks Justin... but this one won't catch `1.2.12` for example. Off-topic: I really like when you say "On a really good day, it'll be Brazil." in your SO profile! :D

Comment: @TimPietzcker - D'oh, I forgot that last `+`. My bad. Edited.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi - O Brasil, meu pais favorito no mundo! Rio and Curitiba in particular. Cheers.